# PHP script, getting a pending request list

Tags: php, android, json

I have only just started writing the PHP script to power the backend of my android app. What i'm currently trying to do is run a PHP script that goes into my database called send_friendreq and the table called pending_req and gets the row toUser and adds it to an array. The only problem i'm currently having is the fact that I cannot get the PHP script to run correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code for the PHP script that I currently have. Thank you very much for the help!

```
if (isset($_POST['Username']) && isset($_POST['FriendReq']))
{
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $usernamebeingreq = $_POST['FriendReq'];
    $i=0;

    //$sqlCheck = "SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = '" . $usernamebeingreq . "'";
    //$resultCheck = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCheck);

    //if(!$resultCheck)
    //{
    //echo "Invalid Username";
    //}
    //else
    //{
    $sql="SELECT fromUser FROM pending_req WHERE toUser='&username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $array = array();
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $i++;
    }
    for($x=0;$x<$i;$x++)
    {
        echo $array[$x];
    }
    if(!$result)
    {
        echo 'Failed';

    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode($array[$x]);
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

If you have suggestions on something that would work better / more efficiently / safer, please let me know!

Comment: You appear to be mixing calls to MySQL and Postgres.

Comment: @HoboSapiens not sure what you mean by Postgres

Comment: Your query is executed with a call to `mysqli_query()`, part of the MySQL API, but you're trying to fetch the data with `pg_fetch_array()`, part of the PostgreSQL API. You can't mix the two.

Comment: @HoboSapiens So should I take our my MySQL_query statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you are trying to get json of results from your query. try this code.

```
if (isset($_POST['Username']) && isset($_POST['FriendReq']))
{
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$usernamebeingreq = $_POST['FriendReq'];
$i=0;

//$sqlCheck = "SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = '" . $usernamebeingreq . "'";
//$resultCheck = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCheck);

//if(!$resultCheck)
//{
//echo "Invalid Username";
//}
//else
//{
$sql = 'SELECT fromUser FROM pending_req WHERE toUser='. $username ;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(!$result) {
    echo 'Failed';
}elseif($result){

    $myArray = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great response! I tried this code and sent a post. I got more luck, but not quite fixed. It goes to the "Failed" message of the code.

Comment: Looks like I finally got it work. I changed the query from

$sql = 'SELECT fromUser FROM pending_req WHERE toUser='. $username ;
too     $sql = "SELECT fromUser FROM pending_req WHERE toUser='$username'" ;
And now i'm getting the correct results! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you query syntax seems to be not correct plz modify as :

```
 $sql="SELECT fromUser FROM pending_req WHERE toUser='$username'";
```

Comment: fromUser is the person who sent the request.

Comment: @Brockify i mean to say useing $ instead of & in query

Comment: I see what you mean now, I changed that, but i'm still having problems. When I run a post on it, I still get 500 Server Error.

Comment: did you run this service on browser?

Comment: Yes, I changed the Query and looks like I got it to work. I'll add a comment to @Aman response. Thanks.